# How to manage update command using CQRS pattern for multiple scenarios?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, cqrs, clean-architecture

I am using the CQRS pattern and have come across a scenario where I need some help. To understand the issue let's say we have an entity `User` which has `UserId, FirstName, LastName....` in an application `AppA` I only need to update the `FirstName` and for this, I have the below command:

```
public sealed record UpdateUserCommand(int UserId, 
    string FirstName) : IRequest
```

Then I have another application `AppB` that another developer is working on and he is sharing the library using the CQRS pattern. From AppB the developer wants to update `FirstName & LastName`. The above command is changed to:

```
public sealed record UpdateUserCommand(int UserId, 
    string FirstName, LastName) : IRequest
```

This change has broken my code in `AppA`. I need help to understand what is the best practice to handle such a situation. If I am understanding the CQRS correctly then shouldn't be the all commands be specific for each scenario and in this case I need to have two commands as follow?

```
public sealed record UpdateUserFirstNameCommand(int UserId, 
    string FirstName) : IRequest

public sealed record UpdateUserFullNameCommand(int UserId, 
    string FirstName, LastName) : IRequest
```

shouldn't I use them in each separate application? Please help me with how should I implement it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary defense against this sort of problem is ensuring that your commands are backwards compatible.  The problem realized here is not specific to CQRS - almost every form of messaging has it.

A good resource to review would be David Orchard's essays on XML schema:

- [Versioning XML Vocabularies](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/12/03/versioning.html)
- [Extensibility, XML Vocabularies, and XML Schema](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/10/27/extend.html)

But the TL;DR is that you don't add mandatory fields to message schema that are already released to the world.  Either you treat the new fields as optional, or you start over with a new schema.